# Google Analytics content segmentation

Tags: google-analytics

The content on my website is about food recipes. I wanted to track the content by two categories only: main courses, and salads.
So I created two advanced segments in Google Analytics, and categorized it by how the URL starts with.
Now to see the segments, I always need to go to My Customizations > Advanced Segments and choose the desired segment.
Isn't there any way to integrate them somehow into Dashboard, or with other results?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save an Advanced Segment to the dashboard, BUT there's a much faster way to apply Advanced Segments.

In the top right of your analytics window, there's a button that says "Advanced Segments". You can click it to get a drop down window of your advanced segments and select them from there. It's much faster this way (you can apply the segmentations while viewing the data you want to segment).

That said, it's not clear if Advanced Segmentation is the feature you should be using for what you want (since you haven't said how you're trying to analyze the data).

[image]

Comment: For anyone who views this now, it is OUT OF DATE.